# apple push notifications script not working suddenly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ssl, apple-push-notifications

1. How can I test if my development ASPN certificate is working?
2. My python script gives the following error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "pushnot.py", line 15, in <module>
       wrapper.notify()
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/notifications.py", line 194, in notify
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 215, in connect
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 161, in connect
     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 333, in connect
       self._real_connect(addr, False)
     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 323, in _real_connect
       self.do_handshake()
     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
   ```

Any idea why?

Comment: Facing the same problem... Guys any update on this ?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with python. I am using PHP in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using TLSv1 instead of SSLv3 to make a connection to the APNS server. The problem is with the python SSL library linking against the outdated OSX OpenSSL library (v0.9.8 on my machine). This version apparently no longer makes correct connections to the APNS server when SSLv3 is used. So instead, set the ssl_version to PROTOCOL_TLSv1 when setting up your connection, like so:

```
sock = socket()
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, certfile=certfile)
sock.connect(('sandbox.push.apple.com, 2195))
```

And you should no longer get the handshake failure error.